# How to use keyboard shortcuts globally

Tags: reactjs, keyboard-shortcuts

I use the react-hotkeys library.

I have this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  render(){
     return <Page />
  };

}

class Page extends React.Component {
   ...
   render(){
     return <DataTable />
   };
}

class DataTable extends React.Component {
   ...
   shortCutsKeymap = {
      'MOVE_NEXT_PAGE': ['right'],
      'MOVE_PREV_PAGE': ['left']
   };

   handleShortCuts = {
      'MOVE_NEXT_PAGE': (event) => {console.log('next')},
      'MOVE_PREV_PAGE': (event) => {console.log('prev')},
   };

   render(){
      return (
         <HotKeys keyMap={this.shortCutsKeymap} handlers={this.handleShortCuts}>
            ...
         </HotKeys>
      );
   };
}
```

Shortcuts only work when I click on a data table - that is, I set focus. I need the keyboard shortcuts to work anywhere in my application without having to click on a data table.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of the package you are using. I've installed version
`react-hotkeys": "^2.0.0-pre3"` and it has a `GlobalHotKeys` component which you export like:

```
import { GlobalHotKeys } from 'react-hotkeys'
```

You can use it like so:

```
<GlobalHotKeys keyMap={keyMap} handlers={handlers} />
```